# Can I use "ain't" in this context?

Tags: word-usage, contractions, placement

I have this original sentence:

> I have never been to that supermarket across the street.

I would like to add the informal term "ain't".

How do I integrate it in?

> I **ain't** never been to that supermarket across the street.
>
> I **ain't** ever been to that supermarket across the street.
>
> I **ain't** been to that supermarket across the street.

Out of the three sentences (sentence 1, 2 & 3), which one is proper and preferable?

Comment: In what context? In **formal** English, one does not use *ain't*, and in **informal, colloquial**, English, one might hear *any* of the above, whether grammatically "correct" or not. It is much like asking which finger is preferable to use to pick one's nose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example would be most common:

> I ain't never been to that supermarket across the street.

That said, I would discourage you from trying to incorporate "ain't" into your speech. Besides the fact that it implies a lack of education, it's really difficult to use it and to sound natural. I moved to Kentucky about 20 years ago, and it's taken me that long to figure out how and when to use **ain't** and not have people look at me funny.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is what I want!